# Pandas dataframe initialization changes the value of the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju7sv.jpg)

Please look at the screenshot attached.

I created a Dataframe **df**
then Initialized another Dataframe **tesla** which holds **df**

Then I perform my Manipulations on **tesla** and then when I check back on df

**df** has changed too.

Why is this happening?

I have been using Pandas for a long time now and haven't noticed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with `copy`, then it will not change the original df when you apply change in the new df

```
tesla=df.copy()
```